# JAVASCRIPT soql QUERY IN VISUALFORCE PAGE

Tags: visualforce, soql, javascript

this is my javascript code in vf page.
`'csvExtdIdRecordValues'` its a type of array.
i am pushing names in it.

```
csvExtdIdRecordValues.push(field[key]);
```

**And here i am facing error:

----------------------------**

```
var leadRec = sforce.connection.query(
    'select id,name from Account where name like (\'' + csvExtdIdRecordValues+ '\')' );
```

**This is the  Error is:**

> faultstring: "MALFORMED_QUERY: ↵name from Account where name like
>   ('CSVimport_1,CSVimport_2,CSVimport_3↵
>   ^↵ERROR at Row:1:Column:44↵Bind variables only allowed in Apex code"

==================================

Even i tired like this also:

```
var leadRec = sforce.connection.query(
    'select id,name from Account where name = (\'' + csvExtdIdRecordValues+ '\')' );
```

### Same error i got.

Even like this is also i tired but no luck:

```
var queryResult = sforce.connection.query('Select Name,Id From Account where name LIKE  (\'' + leadRec.join('\',\'') + '\')' );
```

Guys Could you pls help me out in this

Thanks & regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use **IN** instead of **LIKE** when checking against a collection..

```
var leadRec = sforce.connection.query(
    'select id,name from Account where name in (\'' + csvExtdIdRecordValues+ '\')' );
```